# Why are only unitary operations allowed in quantum information theory?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-error-correction

In the quantum information theory, any operations for a quantum state have to be unitary operations. Why is this restriction needed? Can't we make a non-unitary operation to a state? I know that a unitary operation is a reversible operation, but I don't even know why it is necessary.

Comment: And I understant a measurement is not a unitary operation. I'm talking about the operations except measuring a state.

Comment: The typical way to evolve a state is by time evolving it under a Hamiltonian (c.f. the schrodinger equation), which is hermitian and so generates unitary dynamics.  If you have dissipation and go to an effective picture, then unitarity assumptions break down. (Though the full dynamics of the whole system are always unitary)

Comment: Thanks. I understand your answer. By the way, I was thinking the reason of my question and I found the following theorem:Let $U\in Mat_n(\mathbb{C})$. Then $U$ is a unitary matrix$\iff \forall \mathbb{x},\mathbb{y}\in \mathbb{C}^n, (Ux,Uy)=(x,y)$. In the quantum information theory, a state has to be a unit vector. Is this one of the reasons whay any operators have to be unitary?

Comment: Yep, the unitary operations preserve unit vectors and so, probability.

Comment: OK. I think I understand what I was wondering. Thanks a lot.

Comment: in general, it is not true. In quantum information one can, and often does, consider more general maps that are not necessarily unitary. This can be useful for example because it allows to take into account with the same formalism "classical operations" such as feedback/feedforward of measurement results, noise, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is this restriction needed?

Here's a pretty simple way to convince yourself this is true:

Applying any physical action (up to measurement) on a state essentially means exposing it to a specific Hamiltonian $H$ and using that Hamiltonian to evolve that state in time (the only way to evolve a state in time nontrivially is through the Hamiltonian) through the Schrodinger equation

$$H(t)|\psi(t)\rangle = i\partial_t|\psi(t)\rangle.$$

The solution to this equation is given by

$$|\psi(t)\rangle=U(t,0)|\psi(0)\rangle,$$

where $U(t,0)$ is an operator that satisfies

$$H(t)U(t,0)=i\partial_tU(t,0).$$

The solution of this equation is well known, and is given by the so-called *Dyson series*

$$U(t,0)=\text{T}\exp\left(-i\int_{0}^{t}H(t')\mathrm{d}t'\right),$$

where the $\text{T}\exp$ represents the *time-ordered exponential* (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_series) for the full discussion).

The important thing to note is that the Hamiltonian $H$ is a Hermitian operator (by the axioms of quantum mechanics), and consequently $U(t,0)$ is a Unitary operator. Since any physical operation on a state really corresponds to altering the Hamiltonian and using that to evolve the state, we see that any operation applicable to quantum information must be unitary.

> Can't we make a non-unitary operation to a state?

The answer is technically no but realistically yes. As I just demonstrated, any operation on a state that evolves it in time must be unitary. However, that is only if the Hamiltonian is Hermitian. So what would it mean to have a non-Hermitian Hamiltonian?

Well, consider dividing our system (Hilbert space) into two subsystems, the internal system $\mathcal{H}_{i}$ and the environment $\mathcal{H}_{e}$. That is, $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_{i}\otimes\mathcal{H}_{e}$. Then we know that $H$ is Hermitian when acting on the entire system $\mathcal{H}$, but we aren't guaranteed that $H$ is Hermitian when acting on just the internal system $\mathcal{H}_i$. In particular, if there is some interaction between the internal system and the environment, states in the internal system can "bleed" into the environment. This effectively leads to a non-Hermitian form of the internal Hamiltonian, with eigenvalues

$$E_n-i\Gamma_n,$$

leading to the time evolution

$$|n(t)\rangle=e^{-iE_nt}e^{-\Gamma t}|n(0)\rangle.$$

That is, the eigenstates in the internal system decay into the environment over time. This effectively leads to a non-unitary time evolution in the internal system. A great reference for this type of "non-Hermitian quantum mechanics" is [this book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/nonhermitian-quantum-mechanics/134430A6587FF19542FD4A47325BF60E) by Nimrod Moiseyev.

This effect on non-isolated systems is actually *very* important in quantum information, when you want to actually build a quantum computer. Isolating the environment to maintain unitarity becomes a huge challenge, that is still being solved.

I hope this helped! If anything was unclear, just leave a comment and I'll try to explain it in more detail.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Bob. I will try to read your answer and I will ask a question if something is unclear for me.

Comment: Wouldnt the joint Hilbert space be $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_i \otimes \mathcal{H}_e$ ?